# What does the notation " (2, 3] " mean?

Tags: notation

I know [2, 3]. But (2, 3]?

The question's solution was given: 
The range of value of x is (2, 3]

Comment: $(2,3] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 2 < x \leq 3\}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Note that in some countries it is written $]2,3]$ (a much better notation in my opinion, since it avoids things like $(2,3)$ which are very easy to mistake for couples).

Comment: Ah thanks!!! Understood

Comment: @CaptainLama In what countries? I know that L.W. Tu uses it in his "An introduction to manifolds" but I have not seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @HenryW. That notation is used (or was a couple of decades ago, not sure about nowadays) in [Sweden](https://sv.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%B6ppet_intervall).

Comment: It is the only notation used in France for instance. I believe I have seen it elsewhere but can't remember precisely where.

Answer (score 1):

The notation "]" means included,
the notation ")" means not included.

in your case:
It means every number between $2 < x \le 3$